# Does the dot notation above a variable not always mean a derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, unit-of-measure

I came across the equation:

$\frac {\partial v} {\partial t}= g \dot v - \frac {v^2} r$

Where $v$ is a velocity in $\frac m s$, $r$ has units of $m$, and $g$ is gravity (units of $\frac m {s^2}$). Normally I’d expect $\dot v$ to mean “the derivative of $v$ with respect to $t$” or $\dot v = \frac {\partial v} {\partial t}$. However, if that’s the case here then the units of the equation don’t work. The only way the units work is if $\dot v$ is dimensionless.

Is there some other common meaning of the dot above $v$?

Comment: Usually $\dot v$ indicates the time detivative, where does the equation come from?

Comment: Looks like a misprint. In general $\dot v=g-cv^2$ is the free fall (down, where the axis points down) with air friction.

Comment: The equation comes from equation 1 of this paper (doi: 10.1111/maps.12645) which is describing the velovity of a dust particle entering the top of the atmosphere. @LutzL A misprint would make sense as the equation is indeed intended to describe free fall with air friction. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ORL Can you link the original paper?

Comment: @gimusi sure thing, here’s the link https://doi.org/10.1111/maps.12645

Comment: @ORL Can you find the paper Love and Brownlee 1991?

Comment: @gimusi here’s the DOI link https://doi.org/10.1016/0019-1035(91)90085-8 to the Love and Brownlee 1991 paper. I put the paper here (https://expirebox.com/download/31e62e2a133f57c0611f31706e65f7b0.html) in case you have trouble accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to the original paper after *Love and Brownlee 1991* it seems there is a typo and that the symbol $\dot v$ is wrong

[image]

Note that in the paper the symbol $\hat v$ has been used to indicate the velocity direction and probably the typo was originated by that.